# Perform logout segue

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfuser

I have this error :

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CustomLogin.LogoutViewController logoutButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7feaf340ea70'`

I have 3 VCs, of which two are ok, howeverI think that the third one - logoutviewcontroller has an error. I connect the LogOutViewController's orange UIButton to the Login View Controller and call the segue LogOut. There is the code in the LogIn View Controller:

```
@IBAction func loggedOut(sender: AnyObject) {

    PFUser.logOut()


    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loggedOut", sender: self)

    var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Success", message: "You have logged out", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    alert.show()

}
```

What is wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: could you tick the green checkmark at my answer to mark the problwm as solved :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `IBAction` isn't set up properly in the *Storyboard*. In the *Storyboard*, the action that is defined is linked to a method called `logoutButton:`, but the method in your code is called `loggedOut:`.

I would recommend to delete the action in Interface Builder and reconnecting it with your method in code.

Comment: sure no problem :) just don't forget to tick the green checkmark :)